# saving RDD[Elem] to an XML file

Tags: xml, scala, rdd

I have an RDD of type Elem:

```
val clientXml: RDD[Elem] = parsedClient.filter(s => s.isSuccess).map(s => convertToXML.clientToXML(s.get))
```

This RDD contains a collection of elements of type Elem and each element looks like this:

```
<client>
  <first>Alexandra</first>
  <last>Diaz</last>
  <title></title>
  <addresses>
    <address>
      <type>Home</type>
      <addr1>3255 Marsh Elder</addr1>
      <addr2></addr2>
      <city>La Jolla</city>
      <province>CA </province>
      <county>United States</county>
    </address>
  </addresses>
</client>
```

I would like to save the entire RDD to an XML file is the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>.
    <client>
      <first>Alexandra</first>
      <last>Diaz</last>
      <title></title>
      <addresses>
        <address>
          <type>Home</type>
          <addr1>3255 Marsh Elder</addr1>
          <addr2></addr2>
          <city>La Jolla</city>
          <province>CA </province>
          <county>United States</county>
        </address>
      </addresses>
    </client>
```

so far I have managed to save one element using the following method. But I need to save all the elements in one file:

```
val clientElem: Elem = clientXml.treeReduce((a,b) => a) 

XML.save("C:/Temp/Client.xml", clientElem.copy(), "UTF-8", true)
```

please note that `.saveAsTextFile()` is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by converting the `RDD[Elem]` into a `List[Elem]`:

```
val clientXmlList: List[Elem] = for (address <- clientXml.collect().toSeq.toList) yield {
      address
    }
```

then created a data node with the elements in the `List[Elem]` embedded in the `Elem`:

```
val clientXmlElemData: Elem = <data>
  {clientXmlList.map(p => p.copy())}
</data>
```

then used the XML.write() method to write to the XML file:

```
// create a null DocType so that the docType is not inserted to the output XML file
val doctype = null

// create a FileWriter which writes to a file "C:/Temp/Client.xml"
val file = new File("C:/Temp/Client.xml")

// create a BufferedWriter to write to the file "C:/Temp/Client.xml"
val bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))

// write the clientXmlElemData node to the file setting write xml declaration to true
XML.write(bw, clientXmlElemData, "UTF-8", true, doctype)

// close the BufferedWriter after the file has been created
bw.close()
```